# Android upload and download of multimedia contents

Tags: android, json, mongodb, storage, multimedia

I had an idea for an app: this app involves upload and download of multimedia data (photos, videos, audios, etc.) from the app to and by a server. Before I begin development, I'm studying all the possible solutions for the data transfer problem.

In another app I developed I had a similar problem with photos; I used an App - Servlets (via Tomcat) - MySQL workflow, and the JSON format to transfer the photo informations. For the photo bytes, I used a very rough solution: the photo ByteArray[] was a text field of the JSON (something like bytes: "[0, 0, 223, 23...]"), and I worked with it by storing it as a BLOB on the DBMS and parsing it back "textually" on the app when I needed to visualize the image. It worked, but it was very awkward...

I wonder if there are better solutions, that possibly are more general for the multimedia content (audio, video, etc.) and possibly more elegant.
Maybe some DBMS (for example, MongoDB?) or servers are more suitable for this kind of work?

Comment: Well since you used the tag MongoDB will just store as binary directly ( see [BSON Types](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/bson-types/) ). But you really could not have asked a broader question than this.

Comment: Yes, I know it isn't a very specific question... I was just "looking around" and wondered if talking directly with other devs could help. :)